# Is this sentence " They can't open what they absolutely know is a door " grammatically correct?

Tags: sentence-construction

> I’m telling them they can’t open ***what they absolutely know is a door***.

The context is, " To ensure their young kids' safety, a couple kept lying to them that their sliding glass door is just a window."

I feel confused about the objective clause of the verb "open" .

I'm wondering if the above example has something wrong in the highlighted clause. Is there anyone who can help to parse this construction? Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, it's fine. What I absolutely know is that this is a door. You can google "know something absolutely" or "absolutely know something".

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding.  What I felt confused about is not the usage of the 
 adverb "absolutely", but the clause started by " what".  In my opinion, the verb " open" should be followed semanticallly by the object " the door".  Thanks to Seowjooheng who reminds me of the fused relative  clause which I think is the best answer to my question.

Comment: That is just an embedded clause. I saw what I considered to be a terrible situation. We play what we thought of as good music.

Comment: By the way, I feel a little angry about the downvote.  Please note this site is to help people to improve English , not to depress them.  What is the true principle for your  downvotes?

Comment: A good site for English learning is supposed to encourage people to interact positively,  to be helpful to clear confusions. Frankly, the management of this site has not done the best.

Comment: Try not to take downvotes or close votes personally; they're seldom meant as insults. It's good practice to leave a comment explaining a downvote; that doesn't seem to have happened here. If I were to guess, someone reacted to the open-ended "is there anything wrong here" nature of the question. Simple proofreading questions are not covered here. But your question is not that; it focuses on a specific part of the example; and if anyone thinks a question is off-topic they ought to vote to close rather than downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I’m telling them they can’t open **what they absolutely know is a door**.

The example is fine though [**know absolutely** is more common than **absolutely know**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=know+absolutely%2Cabsolutely+know&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

> what they absolutely know is a door

is a fused relative clause the same as

> that which they absolutely know is a door